# BGA Microcontroller Only Works with Finger Pressing

Tags: pcb-assembly, bga

I have a PCBA with a BGA microcontroller on it. I found that two UART pins send/receive garbled output unless I press my finger down on the BGA package itself.
I've seen this on a few boards and I assume something went wrong with the assembly (done by a professional board house) but I don't know what. The board house assures me they did bake the components before assembly as I keep re-using them from the same batch.

The footprint lines up with the datasheet and worked well on a different board.
Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: Does this board house X-ray the mounted BGA? They had better because that's half the reason you get a board house to mount your BGA for you. Sounds like they didn't if the assurance they gave you was that they baked it instead of just saying that they x-rayed it.

Comment: They actually did X-Ray and it looked correct

Comment: Hmm that's a much more interesting problem then. No ultrasonic cleaning involved? The pads are sufficiently flat from a gold ENIG boards I assume? Try scoping those lines with your pressure applied, not applied, and with wavering pressure and see what it looks like. Or perhaps, just drive the lines hi and press down and release and see if it is an intermittent connection the X-ray is somehow not picking up.

Comment: On the last build I saw the same connectivity issue, but the board house did not bake the components. The X-ray looked correct then, but a dye and pry test revealed there was a void under the UART power rail's pad. So my thought was if they baked the components this time it wouldn't come up. But it still did for some reason

Comment: No ultrasonic cleaning, and ENIG finish

Comment: Send it out to experts.  i.e. somebody who isn't the board house who runs X-ray.  There are plenty unbiased professional test labs out there.

Comment: Could it be a problem with bending of the board and components? Can you give more information about the Board (images, Layout) and components involved (links to datasheets)?

Comment: I once had the problem, that the BGA pads itself detached from the substrate (probably due to tensions in the BGA package introduced by rapid temperature changes). Putting force down by pushing, again reconnected the pad. If the via is located right below the pad, x-ray might not be able to pick up the defect (or the pad detached in transport).

Comment: I wonder if the X-ray would have high enough resolution to pick up a BGA that was initially properly soldered but the joints fractured later from thermal cycling or whatever.

Comment: The xray doesnt show you the z axis details. If you press the IC down that’s the z axis. Can you provide a footprint detail and a photo?